# Is a distinct selection on a primary key ever useful?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I ran into the (equivalent of the) following selection in a stored procedure:

```sql
select distinct primary_key_column, column1, column2, (more columns...)
from table1
where (blah blah blah....)
```

And I can't figure out why the `distinct` is there. My understanding is that primary keys can't be repeated, so the distinct will just burn CPU time on unnecessary comparisons.

...unless distincting on multiple columns has some effect when *at least one* of the columns is duplicated between records. That isn't my understanding of how distinct works, but I may misunderstand it.

Is it really a no-op here, or am I missing something? SQL Server 2008 R2, if relevant.

Comment: It would be redundant for sure if there is only a single table in the query. But if there is a join the distinct may be needed to get the correct results.

Comment: Check the execution plan, SQL Server may be intelligent enough to ignore the DISTINCT.

Comment: In theory primary keys can be added/dropped/altered, and suddenly select distinct makes sense. (Rarely never happens in practice.)

Comment: Just as a note: SQL Server 2008 and 2008 R2 are **out of extended support** by now - https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/the-end-of-sql-server-2008-and-2008-r2-extended-support/ - time to upgrade!

Comment: No join involved in this case, but good to know anyway. And yes, we have an upgrade in the works. (edit: while I think the answer I accepted is correct, a better one would note the join thing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the single-table scenario you describe, the DISTINCT is irrelevant:

```
--Table 1 with PK
create table dbo.PK_Test1 (
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    Name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    Age INT NULL
)

--Table 2, no PK
create table dbo.PK_Test2 (
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    Name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    Age INT NULL
)


--Populate both tables
insert  dbo.PK_Test1 (Name, Age)
select  left(a.Name, 30) Name, a.[object_id]
from    sys.objects a
        cross join sys.objects b

insert  dbo.PK_Test2 (Name, Age)
select  left(a.Name, 30) Name, a.[object_id]
from    sys.objects a
        cross join sys.objects b


--Check Plans
select  distinct *
from    dbo.PK_Test1

select  distinct *
from    dbo.PK_Test2
```

The plans for both SELECTS are as follows:

[image: Execution Plans]

As you can see, SQL Server will omit the "Hash Match (Aggregate)" step in the first plan.